# Grouping two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query?
I have a table as

```
    sender_user_id  receiver_user_id        
        2               3           
        3               2           
        2               7       
        2               8           
        7               3           
       10               6               
        2               3
```

and i want to group the columns by `sender_user_id` and `receiver_user_id` also
`(sender id=2 and receiver_id=3)` and `(sender id=3 and receiver_id=2)` should be grouped as one column with `max timestamp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the GROUP BY as a subquery and do the CONCAT afterwards

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(sender_user_id,' ',receiver_user_id) sender_receiver,
    max_datestamp
FROM
(
    SELECT sender_user_id,receiver_user_id, max(datestamp) max_datestamp
    FROM temptable GROUP BY sender_user_id,receiver_user_id
) A;
```

Make sure temptable is properly indexed

```
ALTER TABLE temptable ADD INDEX sender_receiver_ndx (sender_user_id,receiver_user_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT CONCAT(sender_user_id,' ', receiver_user_id ) as newcolumn, max(datestamp)
from temptable
group by CONCAT(sender_user_id,' ', receiver_user_id ) ;
```

[Really crude, quick, SQLFiddle Solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16592/1)

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you mean. Do you want something like

```
   group by sender_id, reciever_id
   order by timestamp desc
```

Comment: i have entries with sender_id=2 and receiver_id=3 also i have an entry  with sender_id=3 and receiver_id=2 so this should be group into one column

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select max(timestamp) from yourTable group by sender_user_id, receiver_user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do this with a GROUP BY combining the two columns. You could try a UNION

```
SELECT user1,user2,MAX(timestamp) FROM 
(SELECT
  sender_user_id AS user1,
  receiver_user_id AS user2,
  timestamp
FROM table
) AS table1
UNION DISTINCT
(SELECT 
  receiver_user_id AS user1,
  sender_user_id AS user2,
  timestamp
FROM table) AS table2
GROUP BY user1,user2
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT *, MAX(timestamp) FROM <my_table> GROUP BY sender_user_id, receiver_user_id
```